# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to run a script that would take in 3 variables using "GET" and then return the result back to the activity calling the script. I have written my php code and am trying to test it using postman, but every time i give it arguments it returns = unexpected ''

here is my php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');


class User{
    private $db; 
    private $connection;
    function __construct(){
    $this->db = new DB_connection();
    $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();
    }
    public function transaction($emailval, $merchantid, $amount){
        $query= "select amount from wallet_user where email = '$emailval'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
        $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
        $resultval = floatval($row['amount']);
        //echo resultval;
        if ($resultval >= $amount){
            $sql = "Select * from wallet_merchant where merchant_id = '$merchantid'";
            $resultm = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultm) > 0) { 
                $query2 = "UPDATE finger.wallet_merchant SET amount = amount + $amount WHERE merchant_id= '$merchantid' ;";
                $query3 = "UPDATE finger.wallet_user SET amount = amount - $amount WHERE email= '$emailval' ;";

                $result2 = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query2);
                $result3 = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query3);

                $json['tsuccess'] = 'Transaction successful!';
                echo json_encode ($json);
                mysqli_close($this->connection);
            }
        }
        else{
            $json['amounterr'] = 'Please add more amount to your wallet!';
            echo json_encode ($json);
            mysqli_close($this ->connection);
            }
    }
}

$user = new User();

if (isset ($_GET['emailval'], $_GET ['merchant_id'], $_GET['amount'] )){
    $emailval = $_GET['emailval'];
    $merchantid = $_GET['merchant_id'];
    $amount = floatval($_GET['amount']);
    if (!empty ($emailval) && !empty($merchantid) && !empty($amount)){
        $user->transaction($emailval, $merchantid, $amount);
    } 
    else{
        echo json_encode("Please enter both fields!");
    }
}

?>
```

I don't understand what I'm missing here. It's not the connection.php script that's giving me any error because i'm running other scripts on it and they run fine, what am i missing?

Comment: Have you looked at the resulting json file? What's on line one?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I've tried to run it on xampp server as well, there is nothing to show except the syntax error.

Comment: Probably should remove `echo resultval;` part way through.

Comment: @NigelRen that was just for testing where the error was coming from, unfortunately i got the same error everytime

Comment: I suggest you remove the `header('Content-Type: application/json')` and or change it to `text/plain` and check for the **full** error message

Comment: Also, when your response is meant to be JSON, you want only **one** output, the encoded JSON. Given your script has multiple points where it can `echo` something, your response has a high chance of being malformed

Comment: You should change last encode to something like `json_encode(["error" => "Please enter both fields!"]);`.

Comment: @NigelRen why? A plain string is perfectly valid JSON

Comment: @Phil - it may be, but all the way through the code all messages are done differently, so I was more looking at consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here `echo resultval;` It will create Invalid json. Remove this echo from your code. Never add output before ant json returned otherwise it will create issue

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');


class User{
    private $db; 
    private $connection;
    function __construct(){
    $this->db = new DB_connection();
    $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();
    }
    public function transaction($emailval, $merchantid, $amount){
        $query= "select amount from wallet_user where email = '$emailval'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
        $row=$result->fetch_assoc();
        $resultval = floatval($row['amount']);       
        if ($resultval >= $amount){
            $sql = "Select * from wallet_merchant where merchant_id = '$merchantid'";
            $resultm = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultm) > 0) { 
                $query2 = "UPDATE finger.wallet_merchant SET amount = amount + $amount WHERE merchant_id= '$merchantid' ;";
                $query3 = "UPDATE finger.wallet_user SET amount = amount - $amount WHERE email= '$emailval' ;";

                $result2 = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query2);
                $result3 = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query3);

                $json['tsuccess'] = 'Transaction successful!';
                echo json_encode ($json);
                mysqli_close($this->connection);
            }
        }
        else{
            $json['amounterr'] = 'Please add more amount to your wallet!';
            echo json_encode ($json);
            mysqli_close($this ->connection);
            }
    }
}

$user = new User();

if (isset ($_GET['emailval'], $_GET ['merchant_id'], $_GET['amount'] )){
    $emailval = $_GET['emailval'];
    $merchantid = $_GET['merchant_id'];
    $amount = floatval($_GET['amount']);
    if (!empty ($emailval) && !empty($merchantid) && !empty($amount)){
        $user->transaction($emailval, $merchantid, $amount);
    } 
    else{
        echo json_encode("Please enter both fields!");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Make sure there is no error and also no other `echo`s before json output